# Statically Regenerate Route-based state-information based on the current Route, using the Route class from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the goal of generating stateful information as if I had navigated to a path manually, when accessing that the path directly from outside of the "application".

For example:
The base component `Index` uses the state to determine which set of routes to consider:

```
render() {
    const $ = this;

    return (
        <SiteConfig.Provider value={$.store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <React.StrictMode>
                    <Route path="/:root" component={PathFinder}/>
                    {(() => {
                        if ($.state.mode === 'web') {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <Header/>
                                    <Banner/>
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route path="/" exact component={Web}/>
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                    </Switch>
                                    <Footer/>
                                </>
                            );
                        } else if ($.state.mode === 'db'){
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <Header/>
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route path="/db" exact component={DB}/>
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                    </Switch>
                                </>
                            );
                        } else {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <ErrorPage/>
                                </>
                            );
                        }
                    })()}
                </React.StrictMode>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </SiteConfig.Provider>
    );
}
```

However this does not work as the rendering of of the `Route` component which instantiates a `PathFinder` component to determine the page's path - is done after the default state is set for the rendering of the `Index` component.

The `Header` component in turn generates its links based off of a contextual *store* type data structure:

```
getNavLinks() {
    const $ = this;

    switch ($.context.get('mode')) {
        case 'database':
            return navLinksDB;

        default:
        case 'web':
            return navLinksWeb;
    }
}
```

But the `Header` is also responsible for the state's mode:

```
<Button variant={'outline-success'} as={NavLink} className="mr-2" activeClassName="active" to={'/db'} onClick={$.toggleSiteMode.bind($)}>Change&nbsp;View</Button>
```

and it calls this

```
toggleSiteMode() {
    const $ = this;

    if ($.context.get('mode') === 'web')
        $.context.set('mode', 'database');
    else
        $.context.set('mode', 'web');
}
```

This store has an event emitter which updates the state on the `Index` and so - this is done too late and is *missed* at the loading of the page.

How can I make an access to '~/db' and regenerate this stateful information?

I don't want to use more and more packages, I'm already using `react-router-dom`and the site size is *absurd* at something in the vicinity of `400KiB` compiled. I also want to avoid using nested routes as all that serves to do is hide away from this issue of generating stateful information based on the current path.

Comment: What sort of "access to '~/db'" do you need? What state are you regenerating? Doesn't appear to be route state in play.

Comment: As simple as it gets I can say that most paths after `~/db` must have a state parameter `mode` set to the string `"db"` and almost everything else needs the same state parameter  to be set to `"web"`. Such that when somebody accesses the website at `~/db` (where tilde means the hostname) then the state seen by all components through the store needs to reflect `"db"`.

Comment: It took a while but I think I see now, you need `this.state.mode` (or similar I assume) to be defined so you can figure out which switch to render. Is this correct? A little off-topic, but what is the point/purpose of saving a ref to `this` as `$`? It really hurts readability.

Comment: The state can be set by proxy via a child by modifying the store which is passed in context. The base application has a listener for changes to the store and updates state accordingly. All components except for the base application seem to respond to state changes. And yes that other question is off-topic and considering how much I've debated my preference for `$` and `_` I don't fancy doing it more in comments.

Comment: Am I best to just use `function matchPath(pathname, options) { ... }` from `./cjs/react-router.js`and its outputs as if I had instantiated a real Route, since I don't want that route to render anyway and I am only after the path information from `location.pathname`?

I found it inside the source for `reat-router.js` andI think I can expose it with just simply `import { matchPath } from 'react-router';`. It appears to take the arguments `...[path, options]` where options is `{ path, exact, strict }`.

Comment: I think you may be able to render an anonymous (inline) component on a match * route so it will have access to the [route-props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props). Basically it would return all the logic after that first `PathFinder` route.

Comment: I think going for the rendering paradigm means I'd have to somehow render before my `Index` component does, instead I opted for `const retMatch = matchPath(window.location.pathname, { ... });` and initialise the state based on its values. This works as I expect. If you think there's a problem with this, I'm all ears.